# Single variable with two type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem stmt: a user calls the function test. He should be able to enter argument as int or string. Output should come. One way is to do function overloading but that would make my code too messy.

I tried this too:

```
def test(a: Optional[int],a:Optional[str]):
    print(a)
```

But as expected got error. Can someone please help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
def test(a: Union[string, int]):
    print(a)
```